# Displaying an error message if a file can't be opened, C++

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm using **fstream** to open up .txt files with C++. So far it's working great. However, I'd like my console to display an error message if the **input_file** can't be opened. How should I go about this?

Snippet:

```
cin >>  in_file_name ;

ifstream in_file(in_file_name.c_str());

in_file_str.assign(istreambuf_iterator<char>(in_file), 
istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ifstream in_file(in_file_name.c_str());
if( in_file.fail() ) {
    cerr << "Error!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Sadly, you can't write portable code to determine exactly what went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`fail()`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/fail/) to determine whether the `ifstream` was successfully opened or not.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [is_open](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/is_open/) method

```
cin >>  in_file_name ;

ifstream in_file(in_file_name.c_str());
if(!in_file.is_open())
{
   cout<<"Can't open the file";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `operator!` to test whether file open was succesful. Example:

```
std::ifstream fs(...);
if (!fs) {
    std::cerr << "Could not open file.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All standard iostreams support a conversion to void*, which allows for testing. This means that you can do `if(!in_file) { ... }`.

Comment: This is actually invoking the overloaded `operator!` (http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/operatornot/).   Either way, I'm not a huge fan, because it's not particularly explicit about what it means.